# Sum of Legendre Symbols for evey number less than $p$

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

If $p$ is an odd prime, show that $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}({\frac{j}{p}})=0$ with $(\frac{j}{p})$ the Legendre Symbol.

I'm not sure if it's enough to say that, because of the Euler's Criteria, there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ values for which $(\frac{j}{p})=1$ so the other values are $-1$, hence it's proved.

I somehow feel like it's not a good proof.

I've also seen that if $p\equiv 3 (4)$ it's true since $(\frac{-j}{p})=-(\frac{j}{p})$, so the terms cancel out, but following this for $p\equiv 1 (4)$ I don't achieve anything.

Thanks

Comment: You are right. I had that hypotesis, but forgot to write it. I'll add it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly good. Another way: the nonzero squares mod $p$ are $1^2 \pmod p$,
$2^2 \pmod p$,..., $(p-1)^2 \pmod p$.  That would be $p-1$, but they're double-counted since $x^2 \equiv (p-x)^2$, so there are $(p-1)/2$ squares mod $p$.